# Помогите составить регулярное выражение для даты на украинском языке

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, vb.net

Есть дата например **06.Вер.2016** как в .NET для поиска такой строки составить регулярное выражение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предположить, что регулярка будет выглядеть так:

```
\b(?<day>\d{2})\.(?<month>Сiч|Лют|Бер|Квiт|Трав|Черв|Лип|Серп|Вер|Жовт|Лист|Груд)\.(?<year>\d{4})\b
```

В группе `day` вернет день, в группе `month` - месяц из перечисленных сокращений (за правильность сокращений не ручаюсь, нашел на просторах интернета), в группе `year` - год.

По мотивам [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c8e9427h(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb)

Answer (score 4):

Лучше использовать специализированные методы для разборка дат:

```
var date = "06.Вер.2016";
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureinfo =
        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("uk-UA");
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date, cultureinfo);
```

Comment: `...для поиска такой строки...`

Comment: Большое спасибо, возможно вопрос изначально был задан неверно, это то что нужно в моем случае.